# AWS SSL Certificate Not Propagating Throughout The Site

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl

I have a SSL Cert from AWS, and the front page works.  We have a CLB, that uses it.

However, if I go any deeper than this, it will not be a secure connection.

We have a splash page as the site is being developed (that has no access to the rest of the page), however we can access the rest of the page in the live environment, and chrome says: "Your connection to the site is not fully secure."(although still https).

What gives?

Comment: 'not fully secure' means the page _is_ TLS (SSL is obsolete) but some _resource(s)_ fetched by the page is(are) _not_; this is also described as **mixed content**. Touch F12 for dev tools and in the network tab mouse to see what resource(s) you are unsafely fetching as http. This has nothing to do with the certificate, which is probably fine.

Comment: Oh!  Okay, makes sense.  Thanks!  Provide an answer, and ill accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem when setting up SSL for a web site. This issue is that your web pages are being requested using HTTPS but the page itself is requesting resources using HTTP.

Start Google Chrome (or similar). Load your web site page. Press F-12 to open the debugger. Press F-5 to refresh the page. Note any lines that look like the following:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mywebsite.com/' was loaded over
>   HTTPS, but requested an insecure image
>   'http://mywebsite.com/images/homepage_top.png'. This content should
>   also be served over HTTPS.

You will then need to edit the HTML content (or page generator such as PHP) to correctly use HTTPS instead of HTTP.